# Why is gunicorn running a module from a different directory?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

Gunicorn 20.0.4 runs an app from a different directory. Folder structure:

```
folder0/
  app.py
folder1/
  app.py
```

In both `app.py` files there is a Flask `app` instance. In `folder0`, I run

```
$ gunicorn app:app
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:8000, I see the app from `folder1` is running.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

*Update 07/11/2020*

The app from `folder0` runs as expected with:

```sh
$ python3 app.py
```

When I rename `folder1` and run `gunicorn app:app` in `folder0`, it can't find my module.

*Update 07/12/2020*

I opened a github issue about this here: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2378

Comment: in folder0, `python` then `import app` than `print(app.__file__)`. Does it show folder0 in the path?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Yes.

Comment: That should be pretty much what gunicorn is doing. Is there any chance you left a prior gunicorn run going?

Comment: Don't think so. Just used `ps ax:grep gunicorn` then `pkill gunicorn`, tried again, same error.

Comment: The next thing I'd do in your position is to look for and remove any `*.pyc` or `__pycache__/*` files.

Comment: Removed the `__pycache__` folders in both `folder0` and `folder1` (no `*.pyc` files); doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The only thing I have left is to rename the `app.py`s to `app0.py` and `app1.py`, and see what happens.